# Microsoft Excel on Mac Error VBA Run-Time 1004 on Application Open - Endless Loop - Cannot Use Excel

Tags: mac, ms-office

When Excel is opened - no matter the document - there is a run-time error as shown in the picture below[image: Click The Link]

clicking on End does nothing but brings up the same error window again, causing a loop that causes Excel to not be usable. Please advise. Thanks! This is Excel on Mac. I tried re-installing already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is posted here:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/975724/excel-for-mac-error-the-application-microsoft-excel-quit-unexpectedly

Delete entire folder that ends in .office